# Game programming advice, double E recogntion?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm making a Flash game for NCEA Level 2 Digitech and I've come across a problem in the code I'm trying to write which is infuriating.

Basically in this piece of code the "e.target" is a letter falling down the screen and the "shootBall" object is  a cannonball which when it hits a letter with e.target.Letter_txt.text matching the next letter in the Word then that letter in the word will no longer be a # symbol. The problem occurs when it only fills in the word up to GRE and won't go any further. My guess is that it has something to do with recognizing E twice but other than that I have no clue.

Here are some things which may help as this is probably confusing as hell.
The e.target is an object.
"shootBall" is an object.
"word_txt" is dynamic text.
"Lives" and "Score" are variables what aren't really important.

```
function checkForBall3(e:Event):void {
if(e.target.hitTestObject(shootBall)) {
    if(word_txt.text == "GREE#") {
        if(e.target.Letter_txt.text == "N") {
            shootBall.visible = false;
            shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
            stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
            e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
            e.target.y = 0;
            e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
            Score = Score + 10;
            word_txt.text = "GREEN"
            Lives = Lives + 1;
            NextLevel("You Did It!");
            }
        }else{
        if(word_txt.text == "GRE###") {
            if(e.target.Letter_txt.text == "E") {
                shootBall.visible = false;
                shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
                stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
                e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
                e.target.y = 0;
                e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
                Score = Score + 10;
                word_txt.text = "GREE#"
                Lives = Lives + 1;
                }
            }else{
            if(word_txt.text == "GR###") {
                if(e.target.Letter_txt.text == "E") {
                    shootBall.visible = false;
                    shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
                    stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
                    e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
                    e.target.y = 0;
                    e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
                    Score = Score + 10;
                    word_txt.text = "GRE##"
                    Lives = Lives + 1;
                    }
                }else{
                if(word_txt.text == "G####") {
                    if(e.target.Letter_txt.text == "R") {
                        shootBall.visible = false;
                        shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
                        stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
                        e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
                        e.target.y = 0;
                        e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
                        Score = Score + 10;
                        word_txt.text = "GR###"
                        Lives = Lives + 1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(e.target.Letter_txt.text == "G") {
                            shootBall.visible = false;
                            shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
                            stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
                            e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
                            e.target.y = 0;
                            e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
                            Score = Score + 10;
                            word_txt.text = "G####"
                            Lives = Lives + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        shootBall.y = -100
        shootBall.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, fire)
        stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, shoot)
        e.target.x = randomRange(xMin, xMax);
        e.target.y = 0;
        e.target.Letter_txt.text = generateRandomString(1)
        Lives = Lives - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have put an extra # symbol, so you never enter the if block. Try changing:

```
if(word_txt.text == "GRE###")
```

to this:

```
if(word_txt.text == "GRE##")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that :P